# Replacing a date column's data in a CSV

Tags: python, csv

From a CSV file, I have a column of dates in terms of (`yyyy-mm-dd`). 
To get a snapshot of the data in years, I want to categorize the data annually by truncating the date data from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy`.

If, for example, I'm looking to edit the "datecolumn" from the "table" (so `table.datecolumn`), how would I use the replace function? Or is there another way?

Comment: Can you give some more context/code? As it is, you could do this in something like Excel (with the basic GUI, not VBA macros) by sorting and filtering by date.

Comment: The context is that I'm tracking the monthly rents of 20,000 properties from 2008 to 2015. The excel sheet has yy-mmm (i.e. 8-Apr means April 2008), so I cleaned it up using Python to get the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: And why do you want to remove the month and day? Excel's sorting and filtering features work well on dates of almost any format.

Comment: In excel right now, I have about 2MM data entries. In addition, the current format of 14-Jan makes the computer think it's 1/14/2015 instead of Jan 2014. 
I want to remove the month and day so I can see a rent distribution of the year 2009 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you get started...

```
import csv
import datetime

date_column_index = 1
with open('infile.csv','rb') as infile, open('outfile.csv','wb') as outfile:
    csvr = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    csvw = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvr:
        temprow = row
        temprow[date_column_index] = datetime.datetime.strptime(temprow[date_column_index],'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y')
        csvw.writerow(temprow)
```

It assumes that there are no headers.

datetime.datetime.strptime creates a datetime object using the input from the csv formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD', and then strftime outputs a string with just 'YYYY.'

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is more on strptime/strftime formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in Excel. I wish it was as easy to specify a date input format as it is to specify a date output format, but fortunately it's just [one concise line](https://superuser.com/questions/335132/how-do-i-parse-a-nonstandard-date-format-in-excel).

In cell `A2`:

```
08-Feb
```

In cell `B2`:

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A2,3)&"-20"&LEFT(A2,2))
```

This gets the `A2` cell's `RIGHT`-most `3` characters, adds a `-` to that, then adds the `A2` cell's `LEFT`-most `2` characters, which creates a string that the `DATEVALUE` function recognizes:

```
2008-Feb
```

And then it can parse the date as an actual date and do all sorts of filtering and sorting and comparisons and such. You can then fill down to create a full column of parsed dates, and either use it to replace the original or leave both columns intact.